# using setattr() for accessing dynamic methods

Tags: python

I'm trying to change some fields proprieties in `QT`.

This is the code:

```
req_fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "street", "city"]
for field in req_fields:
    if getattr(self, field).text() == "":
        setattr(self, field, setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{ border : 2px solid red;}"))
        setattr(self, field, setText("test"))
```

I get the error:

```
setattr(self, field, setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border : 2px solid red;}"))
NameError: name 'setStyleSheet' is not defined
```

I don't understand why the `getattr` function works, and the `setattr` doesn't.

If I manually use:

```
self.first_name.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border : 2px solid red;}")
```

I get the expected result.

Comment: This has nothing to do with getattr or setattr. As the error days, it is the thing you are trying to call to send the result to setattr - setStyleSheet - that is not defined.

Comment: but then why can I directly use setStyleSheet ?

Comment: This isn't even a job for `setattr`. You're not performing an attribute assignment. This is a job for `getattr`, just like you did with `getattr(self, field).text()`. It doesn't matter that `setStyleSheet` has `set` in the name.

Comment: When you use `setStyleSheet` in the `setattr()` it's treated a global variable (which isn't defined). When you use `self.first_name.setStyleSheet` the term `setStyleSheet` is resolved as an attribute of `self.first_name`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, user2357112. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `setStyleSheet` in the `setattr()` it's treated as a global variable (which isn't defined). When you use `self.first_name.setStyleSheet` the term `setStyleSheet` is considered (rightfully) as an attribute of `self.first_name`.

I don't have QT installed, but think something like this would work:

```
req_fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "street", "city"]
for fieldname in req_fields:
    field = getattr(self, field)
    if field.text() == "":
        field.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border: 2px solid red;}")
        field.setText("test")
```